# Storing data on cache with PHP

Tags: php, caching

I have an events calendar.
Each event has a different location on the calendar.
Every time page loads, I empty the event location table and I write the location of the event to the table.

event location table looks like this

```
eventid     location
    1           1
    2           2
    3           1
    4           1
    5           1
    6           2
    7           3
    8           4
    9           5
```

There are some other variables involved but it is pretty much like this. Each event needs to know the previous event's location so that it can decide its own location.

There are also different views of this calendar and each view use the same technique so it is not the healthiest way to solve this.

The question is;
Is there any way to store this table's data on a cache or something like that instead of re-writing the table every single time.

Comment: please take a look at the following links on PHP caching methods: http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/php-caching.php http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Caching-Result-Sets-in-PHP-Costefficient-PHP-acceleration/

Comment: thanks, i am checking them now.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two approaches you can take to cache this data. The easiest is to [`serialize()`](http://www.php.net/serialize) the data and store it in your database. When you need to retrieve the database, query it from the database, [`unserialize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it, and use it as before.

As second approach is to add [memcache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) to your PHP installation and access your data via the memcache functions. [Example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.examples-overview.php):

```
<?php

$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");

$version = $memcache->getVersion();
echo "Server's version: ".$version."<br/>\n";

$tmp_object = new stdClass;
$tmp_object->str_attr = 'test';
$tmp_object->int_attr = 123;

$memcache->set('key', $tmp_object, false, 10) or die ("Failed to save data at the server");
echo "Store data in the cache (data will expire in 10 seconds)<br/>\n";

$get_result = $memcache->get('key');
echo "Data from the cache:<br/>\n";

var_dump($get_result);

?>
```